# How to change the controltype on clientsideevents for devexpress

Tags: c#, javascript, devexpress

I have a combobox and a gridview. What i want to do is, according to combobox selection, one control of the gridview has to change. I tried to do it clientsideevents but couldn't find the right source.

Thanks
Mehmet Serif

Answer (score 0):

@Mehmet,

Check out this sample:

[Example Details: How to filter the grid using the outside combobox](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E142.aspx)

If that doesn't help, then try these [search results](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=combobox&p=T4|P5|57&d=447)